# How to extract the n-th elements from a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm trying to obtain the n-th elements from a list of tuples.

I have something like:

```
elements = [(1,1,1),(2,3,7),(3,5,10)]
```

I wish to extract only the second elements of each tuple into a list:

```
seconds = [1, 3, 5]
```

I know that it could be done with a `for` loop but I wanted to know if there's another way since I have thousands of tuples.

Answer (score 244, accepted):

```
n = 1 # N. . .
[x[n] for x in elements]
```

Answer (score 49):

This also works:

```
zip(*elements)[1]
```

(I am mainly posting this, to prove to myself that I have groked `zip`...)

See it in action:

```
>>> help(zip)
```

> Help on built-in function zip in module **builtin**:
>
> zip(...)
>
> zip(seq1 [, seq2 [...]]) -> [(seq1[0], seq2[0] ...), (...)]
>
> Return a list of tuples, where each tuple contains the i-th element
>      from each of the argument sequences.  The returned list is truncated
>      in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence.

```
>>> elements = [(1,1,1),(2,3,7),(3,5,10)]
>>> zip(*elements)
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 5), (1, 7, 10)]
>>> zip(*elements)[1]
(1, 3, 5)
>>>
```

Neat thing I learned today: Use `*list` in arguments to create a parameter list for a function...

*Note*: In Python3, `zip` returns an iterator, so instead use `list(zip(*elements))` to return a list of tuples.

Comment: and use `**dict` to create keyword arguments: `def test(foo=3, bar=3): return foo*bar` then `d = {'bar': 9, 'foo'=12}; print test(**d)`

Comment: @Wayne Werner: Yep. This stuff was all just passive knowledge (I don't often use it) - but it's good to be reminded now and then so you know where / what to look for...

Comment: True story - I find that in anything I use often enough (Python, vim), I tend to need reminders of neat/cool features that I've forgotten because I don't use them *that* often.

Comment: the *list syntax is pretty useful. any idea where this is described in the official python documentation?

Comment: I only found it in the tutorial: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: This is very neat!

Comment: No longer works, probably this got lost in the transition form Python 2 to 3: "TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable." The zip function does not return a list, but a "zip" object now.

Answer (score 32):

> I know that it could be done with a FOR but I wanted to know if there's another way

There is another way. You can also do it with [map](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) and [itemgetter](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> map(itemgetter(1), elements)
```

This still performs a loop internally though and it is slightly slower than the list comprehension:

```
setup = 'elements = [(1,1,1) for _ in range(100000)];from operator import itemgetter'
method1 = '[x[1] for x in elements]'
method2 = 'map(itemgetter(1), elements)'

import timeit
t = timeit.Timer(method1, setup)
print('Method 1: ' + str(t.timeit(100)))
t = timeit.Timer(method2, setup)
print('Method 2: ' + str(t.timeit(100)))
```

Results:

```
Method 1: 1.25699996948
Method 2: 1.46600008011
```

If you need to iterate over a list then using a `for` is fine.

Comment: A small addition:  In python-3.x the benchmark will show that map only takes a fraction of a millisecond.  That's because it will return an iterator.  method2 = 'list(map(itemgetter(1), elements))' renders the old behavior.

Answer (score 14):

Found this as I was searching for which way is fastest to pull the second element of a 2-tuple list.  Not what I wanted but ran same test as shown with a 3rd method plus test the zip method

```
setup = 'elements = [(1,1) for _ in range(100000)];from operator import itemgetter'
method1 = '[x[1] for x in elements]'
method2 = 'map(itemgetter(1), elements)'
method3 = 'dict(elements).values()'
method4 = 'zip(*elements)[1]'

import timeit
t = timeit.Timer(method1, setup)
print('Method 1: ' + str(t.timeit(100)))
t = timeit.Timer(method2, setup)
print('Method 2: ' + str(t.timeit(100)))
t = timeit.Timer(method3, setup)
print('Method 3: ' + str(t.timeit(100)))
t = timeit.Timer(method4, setup)
print('Method 4: ' + str(t.timeit(100)))

Method 1: 0.618785858154
Method 2: 0.711684942245
Method 3: 0.298138141632
Method 4: 1.32586884499
```

So over twice as fast if you have a 2 tuple pair to just convert to a dict and take the values.

Comment: This is probably obvious but I would mention `dict(elements).values()` will result in one-element dict as opposed to list comprahension or map. This is exactly what I wanted (I was interested in unique touples) (+1 and big thanks for posting) but others might wonder why dict is faster - it's not allocating memory but only checking against existing element.

Answer (score 8):

Timings for **Python 3.6** for extracting the second element from a 2-tuple list.

Also, added `numpy` array method, which is simpler to read (but arguably simpler than the list comprehension).

```
from operator import itemgetter
elements = [(1,1) for _ in range(100000)]

%timeit second = [x[1] for x in elements]
%timeit second = list(map(itemgetter(1), elements))
%timeit second = dict(elements).values()
%timeit second = list(zip(*elements))[1]
%timeit second = np.array(elements)[:,1]
```

and the timings:

```
list comprehension:  4.73 ms ± 206 µs per loop
list(map):           5.3 ms ± 167 µs per loop
dict:                2.25 ms ± 103 µs per loop
list(zip)            5.2 ms ± 252 µs per loop
numpy array:        28.7 ms ± 1.88 ms per loop
```

Note that `map()` and `zip()` do not return a list anymore, hence the explicit conversion.

Comment: `dict().values()` needs `list` as well.

Comment: @Oleg I don't understand in the 'dict` method how the code understands that we want to look at the second element. Is it the defaults in values == 1 ?. Say, one needs to do the same for the 3 or 10th elements. what changes in the dict method?

Answer (score 4):

```
map (lambda x:(x[1]),elements)
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) and [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> from itertools import chain, islice
>>> elements = [(1,1,1),(2,3,7),(3,5,10)]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(islice(item, 1, 2) for item in elements))
[1, 3, 5]
```

This can be useful when you need more than one element:

```
>>> elements = [(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
                (10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15), 
                (20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25)]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(islice(tuple_, 2, 5) for tuple_ in elements))
[2, 3, 4, 12, 13, 14, 22, 23, 24]
```

Answer (score 1):

I liked @daren's answer, but it gives an error that `zip` is not subscribable since you can't slice the `zip` iterator. Instead, you want to add the `zip` into a `list` to extract the elements you want based on the index.

```py
elements = [(1,1,1),(2,3,7),(3,5,10)]
slices = list(zip(*elements))[1]
```

**output:**

```py
(1, 3, 5)
```