# Why is getting second tuple sum in a list quickest as dict?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sum

Intuitively when I want to get the `sum` of the second elements of a tuple in a list, i just use a list comprehension:

```
elements = [(1,2), (3,50), (4, 5000)]
sumOfSecondItems = [x[1] for x in elements]
```

However, I've found many solutions on a [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308102/how-to-extract-the-n-th-elements-from-a-list-of-tuples-in-python). Under many methods, creating a dict and summing it's values turns out to be the fastest.

> How come the `sum(dict.values())` are faster then any other method?

Here are the other methods with it's benchmarks: Credit to the original [author](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13470505/1767754)

```
setup = 'elements = [(1,i) for i in range(100000)];from operator import itemgetter'
method1 = 'sum([x[1] for x in elements])'
method2 = 'sum(map(itemgetter(1), elements))'
method3 = 'sum(dict(elements).values())'
method4 = 'sum(zip(*elements)[1])'

import timeit
t = timeit.Timer(method1, setup)
print('{0:<40}{1:<30}'.format("list Comprehension: ",t.timeit(100)))
t = timeit.Timer(method2, setup)
print('{0:<40}{1:<30}'.format("map: ",t.timeit(100)))
t = timeit.Timer(method3, setup)
print('{0:<40}{1:<30}'.format("dict: ",t.timeit(100)))
t = timeit.Timer(method4, setup)
print('{0:<40}{1:<30}'.format("zip: ",t.timeit(100)))
```

> **Results**:

```
list Comprehension:                     0.461558960271                
map:                                    0.539129069451                
dict:                                   0.198271294849                
zip:                                    1.02714035879
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timing code is not comparing the same thing; with the code:

```
 elements = [(1,i) for i in range(100000)]
```

all the pairs will have `1` as first element and this means that `dict(elements)` will only contain one element.

```
print(dict([(1,2),(1,3)])) # --> displays {1:3}
```

Comment: :D OMG, what a fail!