# Deleting a specific index from list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

This is my list of tuples:

```
my_tuple_list = [((1,2), 2), ((3,6), 4), ((2,4), 3)]
```

I'm not sure how to delete the 1st index [1] from every tuple to give me an output of:

```
[(1,2), (3,6), (2,4)]
```

Comment: Your question is answered here: [How to extract the n-th elements from a list of tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308102/how-to-extract-the-n-th-elements-from-a-list-of-tuples)

Comment: Tuples are inmutable, you cannot delete a value from it IIRC

Answer (score 1):

```
my_tuple_list = [((1,2), 2), ((3,6), 4), ((2,4), 3)]
[element[0] for element in my_tuple_list]
>>> [(1, 2), (3, 6), (2, 4)]
```

Comment: This just keeps the 0th index instead of deleting the first index. While it works for the example provided might not be what is needed