# Join every second element in a list of lists into a string

Tags: python, list

I have a variable called `result` which is equal to this list `[[0, ''], [1, ''], [2, ''], [3, 'x'], [4, 'x']]`. I want to change that list into `'xx'`, so I can print that data to the screen of the player. Anyway I could do this?

My attempt so far:

```py
res = [''.join(ele) for ele in str(result)]
```

Output:

```
['[', '[', '0', ',', ' ', "'", '', "'", ']', ',', ' ', '[', '1', ',', ' ', "'", '', "'", ']', ',', ' ', '[', '2', ',', ' ', "'", '', "'", ']', ',', ' ', '[', '3', ',', ' ', "'", 'x', "'", ']', ',', ' ', '[', '4', ',', ' ', "'", 'x', "'", ']', ']']
```

Comment: Did you ask this question before? I remember another question with a list of green squares like this.

Comment: @ddejohn added my research

Comment: @Barmar have not, must have been someone else?

Comment: Why are you putting the result inside `[]`? You say you want a string, not a list.

Comment: @Barmar can you elaborate

Comment: You wrote `res = [...]` That makes a list. But you said you want your result to be a string.

Comment: Looks like your input is actually a **string**... Where is this "result" coming from?

Comment: Just use `''.join([el[1] for el in result])`

Comment: @ddejohn His input isn't a string, he's turning it into a string with `str(result)`

Comment: Thanks for the help :D, someone gave a solution that worked.

Comment: Yes, I see that now.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't see.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract the n-th elements from a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308102/how-to-extract-the-n-th-elements-from-a-list-of-tuples)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) with a comprehension:

```
>>> result = [[0, ''], [1, ''], [2, ''], [3, 'x'], [4, 'x']]
>>> result_str = ''.join(xs[1] for xs in result)
>>> result_str
'xx'
```